# How can I find the js file name of the function definition from given function name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many external javascript files, now I have very difficult to find which .js file contain function definition of the given function name from inspect element console window.


**I have tried the below**

In the console window I have enter just the function name, the function definition is shown, but I can not find the function definition source .js file.

[image]

Comment: Click on the printed definition, you'll be taken to the source code line under `Sources` tab.

Comment: @11thdimension Thank you very much. It works well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `inspect(setcode)`.

From Devtools docu:

> When passing a function to inspect, the function opens the document up in the Sources panel for you to inspect

Answer (score 1):

You can either use "grep" or find a good editor (VS Code or Atom).

1. About grep you can write

   grep -Ril "[text to search for]" [path to search in]

   in the linux command line [terminal].
2. And in Atom or VS Code you can search for it inside folder using ctrl+shift+f.

Comment: Can you please explain more, currently I am using notepad++ only. Can't I find it from inspect element?

Comment: I just edited the answer. and Atom and VSCode are much better than notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

The JS code gets loaded into the same namespace when they defined globally. Once loaded there is no way to tell from where the object has originated.

This is why you shouldn't pollute the global namespace. You should define objects/classes per file, at least while development/debugging.

[Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/object-oriented-javascript-deep-dive-es6-classes/) is a good place to start to learn about OOP in JS